# Bluetooth headset profile changes to off during calls

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

Recently during calls on Zoom or Google Meet, my headset has changed automatically its profile on Pulseaudio from `HSP/HFP` to `Off`, such that I have to manually change it back to HSP/HFP during the meeting, however after few minutes the annoying behavior repeats again and the headset gets `Off`.

I have tried some issues:

- Added auto_switch profile to false on `default.pa` like [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset#Disable_auto_switching_headset_to_HSP/HFP).
- Removed cookies and user config files on `~/.config/pullse`
- Looked for errors on syslog or pulseaudio log, starting it like `pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1e.log 2>&1`. They didn't show any event happening when the headset gets **off**.
- Tried using *blueman*.
- Removed device and added it again on `bluetoothctl`

None of them changed this annoying behavior, and I wasn't able to find more related issues on the internet. I really appreciate if anyone has a clue of what is happening or what else can I try. Thanks.

SO: Ubuntu 20.04
bluetoothctl: 5.53
pulseaudio 13.99.1